# htaccess redirect excluding one directory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am redirecting from a directory of a site to a new site using the following:

```
Redirect 301 /watches https://newgatewatches.com
```

However I need to now **not** apply the redirect from a certain directory inside that one. So I need to redirect from everything inside `/watches` **except** `/watches/trade`. Is this possible?

### Edit

I also have this in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond $1 !china\.php
RewriteCond $1 !in\.php
RewriteCond $1 !robots\.txt
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^(CN|HK)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !OutsideVisitFrom
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=203.92.71.82 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /china.php [R,L]
```

I have inherited this from the previous dev!

Comment: try to add `RewriteRule ^watches/trade - [L]` before your redirect

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately that hasn't worked

Answer (score 0):

You should better use `RedirectMatch` here to allow for regex like this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(watches/(?!trade).*)$ https://newgatewatches.com/$1
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this rule.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, that is nearly perfect. Unfortunately the following: `https://oldwebsite.com/watches/product/wwlbdgy001by/` and any other folder that deep is not being redirected. Do I need something more?

Comment: That shouldn't happen with above rule. Do you have other rules as well in your .htaccess or any other .htaccess?

Comment: I also have the following:

RewriteCond $1 !china\.php

RewriteCond $1 !in\.php

RewriteCond $1 !robots\.txt

RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^(CN|HK)$

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !OutsideVisitFrom

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=203.92.71.82 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /china.php [R,L]

Comment: I have done that. This is not my code so I am not sure if it is correct!

Comment: Is that complete .htaccess? Isn't it supposed to start with `RewriteEngine` line?

Comment: Moreover that rules is redirecting everything to `/china.php`. You should place my suggested rule before all the rules in your .htaccess